# How Do You Test a Private Method in TCl

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tcl

I am very sorry if this question seems stupid, i am a newbie to TCL and TCLtest, I am trying to perform unit test on a few TCLOO programs, and i am having difficulties testing the private methods  ( the methods called using keyword 'my' ). Guidance needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside the question of whether you *should* test private methods, you can get at the methods by one of these schemes:

- Use `[info object namespace $inst]::my $methodname` to call it, which takes advantage of the fact that you can use introspection to find out the real name of `my` (and that's guaranteed to work; it's needed for when you're doing callbacks with commands like `vwait`, `trace`, and Tk's `bind`).
- Use `oo::objdefine $inst export $methodname` to make the method public *for the particular instance*. At that point, you can just do `$inst $methodname` as normal.

**Consequence:** You should not use a TclOO object's private methods for things that *have* to be protected heavily (by contrast with, say, a private field in a Java object). The correct level for handling such shrouding of information is either to put it in a master interpreter (with the untrusted code evaluating in a [safe slave](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/safe.htm)) or to keep the protected information at the underlying implementation (i.e., C) level. The best option of those two depends on the details of your program; it's usually pretty obvious which is the right choice (you don't write C just for this if you're otherwise just writing Tcl code).

Comment: Sir Thank You very much, Helped a lot. And I went through Clif's Book, the 3rd edition of " Tcl/Tk a Developers Guide ", and the TCLOO section was not much even though it is a good introduction, A tutorial would benefit a lot of people, so whenever you can spare some time, please look into it.

Answer (score 3):

This might look like OT, but bear with me.

Are you sure you have to test private methods? That sounds like testing the implementantion, and thats something you shouldnt do. You should be testing the behavior of your class, and that is tested through its public methods.

If you have a complicated chunk of code in one of the private methods, and you feel it needs to be tested spearately, consider refactoring the code into two separate classes. Make the method that needs testing public in one of the two classes.

That way you avoid having a "god class" that does everything and you get to test what you wanted to test. You might want to read more about Single Responsibility Principle.

If you need specific book titles on refactoring, id recommend "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin. I love that book!

Comment: Sure Point taken, I went through a lot of online discussions about testing a Private Method, and every experienced programmers advice was what you had typed above. Well Being a Novice i tend to make a lot of mistakes. Will learn soon.Thank You.